# Unsupported languages in Azure AD B2C Localized Resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I would like to know how, if possible, to add unsupported languages as a Localized Resource in Azure B2C's authentication process. At present you can only select from a predefined list of languages, but I need to add other languages, Welsh for example, as options for the user.

I understand that this feature is currently in Preview and so the functionality just might not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,this information in [that official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-language-customization#additional-information) may be helpful to you:

> we are planning to provide an extension of this feature that allows
>   you to upload a JSON resource towards 'custom languages'. The feature
>   allows you to specify the name and language code for any language and
>   provide all the translations for that language. If you need this
>   feature, send us your scenario at aadb2cpreview@microsoft.com.

So, I think you can send your scenario to the Email address **`aadb2cpreview@microsoft.com`**. You will get help with that Extension.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Wayne, I think that's probably as good as I'll get for now. Do you know if there are any work-arounds for this scenario? This functionality basically decides whether we use Azure B2C or not

Comment: Hi,@Crwydryn . I'm not sure whether you can resolve your issue by sending emails.  I understand this is important to you. You can just send a email and you will get the details about this feature . Sometimes , it may depends on what your scenario is.